# Ruby data provider?

Tags: ruby, csv, testunit, dataprovider

I am newish to ruby having a java background and i am writing a set of selenium tests against an application

We have a test which needs to be repeated with many values, which is currently stored in a long csv.

In java it is simple to write a data provider and have the test repeated with each value, however after a morning of searching around this area i cant find a suitable solution in ruby.

the only thing i can come up with currently is something like this

```
 [
      ['USD',     'US' ],
      ['GBP',     'UK' ],
      ['EUR', 'FRA']
  ].each do |v1, v2|
      test "creating with #{v1} and #{v2}" do
          #do test
      end
  end
```

but this doesnt look great and the csv of data has 100 sets of data not 3 so would be harder to maintain

Comment: I'm surprised if you say that your code works, it shouldn't.

Comment: @TamerShlash - Why not?

Comment: `[].each do |v1, v2|` doesn't make sense, it should pass only one parameter to the block.

Comment: @Tamer - try it: `[[1,2], [2,3]].each {|i,j| puts "#{i} - #{j}"}` - it is perfectly valid thanks to parallel assignment

Comment: @BroiSatse WOW, looks like I need to review how Array's each methods work!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really testing the right thing. Why are you testing 100 sets of data? Can you provide an example of the expected result and rule for generating the result? Is it possible to generalize the tests to check a small number of rules?

Comment: it is to do with payment options, which is critical to the business, so it is seen as necessary to make sure each combination of country and currency is tested. the values then get passed into selenium tests to ensure payment can be set up, the selenium tests would be the same for each country so want to pass the values into the same test structure

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`CSV` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) this way:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('path/to/csv/file') do |v1,v2|
  test "creating with #{v1} and #{v2}" do
    # do test
  end
end
```

Comment: this solution works thanks, is this common practice though, there doesn't seem to be a clear guide for this type of approach on the internet

Comment: @charlietaylor I don't really know and don't think there's need to test 100 pairs of values, chekcout BSeven's comment on the question.